<$branch.name>: can't evaluate field name in type interface
My Kubernetes template snippet is below:
    # Insert the deploy-environment task
{{- $taskName := printf "deploy-env-%s" $data.envName }}

        - name: {{ $taskName }}
          when: >- 
            {{- range $branch := $data.branchNames }}
            (
              {{ printf "[{{inputs.parameters.git-commit-branch}}] == [refs/heads/%s] " $branch.name }}
            ) || 
            {{- end }}
            (false)

While executing this section I'm getting error:
Error: template: ethos-argo-client-templates/templates/workflows/deploy-all-template.yaml:113:95: executing "ethos-argo-client-templates/templates/workflows/deploy-all-template.yaml" at <$branch.name>: can't evaluate field name in type interface {} Use --debug flag to render out invalid YAML


Is this a [tag:kubernetes-helm] template fragment?  In this context, what exactly is $data?  If branchNames is a list of strings then I could see an error like that.
